# cant run Anaconda-Navigator

Tags: anaconda

after reinstallation it on win10, at startup I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tanya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 209, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tanya\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\Tanya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 119, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
  File "C:\Users\Tanya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 19, in <module>
    from qtpy import PYQT5
  File "C:\Users\Tanya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 215, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

due to conflicts I can not install PySide, Qt, PYQT5.
And why full reinstall doesnt help whith this?

Comment: Did you install Python3?

Comment: @MahmoudNasr yes